# How to add Html element to dynamic list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web programming.Actually I want to create a list in that I have to add elements dynamically to unordered list.I added elements in list dynamically but I have to anchor tag to that each list item.please help me

HTML:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">        
    <input type="button" id="btnid" onclick="getData()"/>
    <p id="p1">
        Insert Content Here working
    </p>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="ulist"  title="nodes list" data-inset="true">                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Element.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.Element[i];
    //console.log(counter.counter_name);
    var newelement=$("<li>"+counter.nodeName+" "+counter.activeCount+" "+counter.inactiveCount+"</li>");                    
    newelement.appendTo("#ulist");                  
    //  alert(counter.nodeName);            
}
```

Comment: Do you want a jquery solution or javascript solution?

Comment: you wanr UI like as below, Right? <ul><li><a></a></li><li><a></a></li></ui>.

Comment: yes i want like <li><a href="#">link</a></li><li><a href="#">link</a></li>

Comment: counter is already a nodeName I think you wish to use nodeValue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
$("<li><a href='#'>"+counter.nodeName+" "+counter.activeCount+" "+counter.inactiveCount+"</a></li>").appendTo("#ulist");
```

Please try with above code snippet. Let me know if you want to set URL based on your field's value.

Comment: working but how to replace # to some html page for every element

Comment: Can you please provide sample URL? You want to set the URL based on 'node' field's value?

Comment: suppose for first element I want set # to one.html for second # to two.html like this how to set for different to all elements

Comment: You want like, yourURL#1, yourURL#2, yourURL#3.

Comment: Make an array of URLs, and use your `i` to append the URL value to each element. If you don't already have this data in the array. `<a href='"+urls[i]+">`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @peter, can you please provide some sample URL for two - three list item?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do something like the following which I quickly wrote here. Using jQuery's built in [`each()` function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) which iterates through an object, or an array for you, without establishing a four loop

```
var list = $('#ulist'),
    urls = new Array('one.html', 'two.html', 'three.html', 'four.html'),
    i = 0;
jsonData.each(function(k,v) {

    var node = v;
    list.append("<li><a href='"+urls[i]+"' title='"+node.nodeName.+"'>"+node.nodeName+" "+node.activeCount+" "+node.inactiveCount+"</a></li>");
    i++;

});
```

This will iterate through the array, giving you the key, and value (`v` being the value which holds your array of data) and allows you to append your data.

Comment: I need html element in middle for every list item

Comment: What does that mean? This is your array, I just changed the var name.